# Google map in my android application is not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I created application using android google map but its not working on my machine but it is working on other machine, I think it is problem of google map api key, how can I solve this problem , I am new to android.
Thanks

Comment: after running application instead of map a image with boxes is appered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Follow this [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

In above article mention

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Change path accordingly your keystore.

generate MD5 Fingerprint. copy MD5 key and go to below link.

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

pass that MD5 key and generate map key.

use that generated map key.

then working fine.

Comment: please upvote also so may other helpful.

Comment: sory boss I dont have enough reputations to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

API key is provided by Google maps API based on you submit MD5 key. This key is seperate per machine so to display map you have to get new API by submitting your MD5 key of your  machine